# Zendesk API get tickets solved today

Tags: rest, api, zendesk, zendesk-api

I want to use Zendesk API https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/ticket_metrics#json-format but I am not sure how can I get metrics like tickets solved today, tickets solved yesterday, tickets solved this week etc.

Is this possible in the Zendesk API?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this data using:

```
GET /api/v2/ticket_metrics.json
```

The return will contain the `solved_at` date:

```
{
  "id": 33,
  "ticket_id": 4343,
  "created_at": "2009-07-20T22:55:29Z",
  "updated_at": "2011-05-05T10:38:52Z",
  "group_stations": 7,
  "assignee_stations": 1,
  "reopens": 55,
  "replies": 322,
  "assignee_updated_at": "2011-05-06T10:38:52Z",
  "requester_updated_at": "2011-05-07T10:38:52Z",
  "status_updated_at": "2011-05-04T10:38:52Z",
  "initially_assigned_at": "2011-05-03T10:38:52Z",
  "assigned_at": "2011-05-05T10:38:52Z",
  "solved_at": "2011-05-09T10:38:52Z",
  "latest_comment_added_at": "2011-05-09T10:38:52Z",
  "reply_time_in_minutes": { "calendar": 2391, "business": 737 },
  "first_resolution_time_in_minutes": { "calendar": 2391, "business": 737 },
  "full_resolution_time_in_minutes": { "calendar": 2391, "business": 737 },
  "agent_wait_time_in_minutes": { "calendar": 2391, "business": 737 },
  "requester_wait_time_in_minutes": { "calendar": 2391, "business": 737 },
  "on_hold_time_in_minutes": { "calendar": 2290, "business": 637 }
}
```

More in the [documentation here](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/ticket_metrics).

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is not a broad-based endpoint to define a ticket status and when that status happened.  Search Endpoint will let you define a status as of now (tickets currently solved).  Incremental Ticket Events endpoint will show you when an event happened (ticket status changed to solved), but is not searchable.  Most people will store the data from Ticket Events endpoint and then you can make it searchable.